# Is it Possible to Recover a Saved Password from MobaXterm

Tags: windows-10, passwords, password-recovery, mobaxterm

I have a password saved in MobaXterm for that I have forgotten.  Is it possible to recover that password from the application somehow?

The password is used to SSH into a Linux portal.  The Linux portal allows resetting the password,  but to do so I need to use the current password.  I could have the admins reset my password, but past experience has shown me that it would take a long time for them to do that (hence my question).

**Details:**

OS: Windows 10

License: Personal Edition

Version: v10.4

Comment: If the password is saved, wouldn't it be easier, to change the password?  If we are talking about a Windows account, you can configure the account, to require the password be changed.

Comment: I edited my question in response.